# Sklearn confusion matrix estimation by cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I am trying to estimate the confusion matrix of a classifier using 10-fold cross-validation with sklearn.

To compute the confusion matrix I am using `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix`. I know that I can evaluate a model with cv using `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score` and `sklearn.metrics.make_scorer` like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cm = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, make_scorer(confusion_matrix))
```

Where `clf` is my classifier and `X`, `y` the feature and class vectors. However, this will raise an error since `confusion_matrix` does not return a float number but a matrix.

I've tried doing something like:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold


def cv_confusion_matrix(clf, X, y, folds=10):
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds)
    cv_iter = skf.split(X, y)
    cms = []

    for train, test in cv_iter:
        clf.fit(X[train,], y[train])
        cm = confusion_matrix(y[test], clf.predict(X[test]), labels=clf.classes_)
        cms.append(cm)
    return np.mean(np.array(cms), axis=1)
```

This will work, but I missing the parallelism that sklearn has with `cross_val_score` and the `n_jobs` parameter.

Is there any way to do this and to take the advantage of the parallelism?

Comment: Have you actually tried the line `cm = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, make_scorer(confusion_matrix))`? What exact error are you getting?

Comment: Also you can always look at the code of [`cross_val_score` in github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L37), specifically lines 135-138 and try implementing the parallel processing part yourself.

Comment: With iris dataset and simple LogisticRegression I got ValueError: scoring must return a number, got [[17  0  0]
 [ 0 15  2]
 [ 0  0 17]] (<type 'numpy.ndarray'>) instead.

Comment: Yes I saw that. Its due to this line - https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L296

Comment: @AlbertoCastaño I tried your solution and it miscalculated the confusion  matrix. I was able to get it working by replacing `cms = []` with `cms=np.empty((n_classes, n_classes))` and replacing `cms.append(cm)` with `cms += cm`.

Comment: @VivekKumar what you did there is a sum over all of the cv confusion matrix. Also take into account that you're initializing your cos to "random" numbers and not to zeros.