# cross validated scoring function with confusion_matrix (sklearn)

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I'm wondering if there is a simple way (apart from the explicit implementation) to compute confusion matrices on different splits with 'cross_val_score', something like:

```
>> cross_val_score(grid_search_CV, X_train, y_train, scoring=make_scorer(confusion_matrix))
```

Comment: make_scorer is used to assign a score according to which different cv folds across different parameters can be compared with each other. So not possible with confusion_matrix.

Comment: But you can use something like the OP did in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669055/sklearn-confusion-matrix-estimation-by-cross-validation